# Java Generics Type DSL with Builder Pattern

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, dsl, builder

I try to create a DSL Java API with the Builder Pattern on Generics Type.

I have the following class:

```
public class Rule<T> {

  private Predicate<T> condition;

  public ConditionBuilder<T> when() {
    return new ConditionBuilder<>(this);
  }

  //setter and getter 

}
```

and the following ConditionBuilder class:

```
public class ConditionBuilder<T> {

  private Rule<T> parent;

  public ConditionBuilder(Rule<T> parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  public ConditionBuilder<T> condition1() {
    parent.setCondition(l -> l == 0); // I would like an Integer
    return this;
  }

  public ConditionBuilder<T> condition2() {
    parent.setCondition(l -> l.length() > 3); // I would like a String
    return this;
  }

}
```

I try to find a solution to set the Generic Type  on the fly as an Integer (resp. String) for the condition1 (resp. condition2).

Is there any Pattern or solution to avoid doing `instanceof` checking ?

Comment: Can you describe the broader task you're trying to accomplish? Why do you need `condition1` and `condition2` to do that? Why not have a `Predicate` as a parameter? Don't use generics if you don't want to use generic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with member methods on `ConditionBuilder<T>`, since you've already constructed `parent` before you invoke either of the `conditionX` methods. As such, you can't constrain the instance "after the fact".

The way I'd do this is by making the `Rule<T>` a parameter of a static method. Then you can use something like:

```
static ConditionBuilder<Integer> condition1(ConditionBuilder<Integer> parent) {
  parent.setCondition(l -> l == 0);
  return parent;
}

static ConditionBuilder<String> condition2(ConditionBuilder<String> parent) {
  parent.setCondition(l -> l.length() > 3);
  return parent;
}
```

Comment: (Note that `Integer` is final, so `T extends Integer` is redundant. May as well just use `Integer` directly)

Comment: This would ruin the builder pattern. I still don't see what role these methods would have. I feel that they shouldn't exist if the OP is going to pursue the builder pattern.

Comment: @4castle it doesn't really matter whether it ruins the pattern; there's no other (obvious) way to affect such a constraint at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a factory pattern instead, because the builder pattern does not fit this situation. Using generics implies that you will accept any type, and so making `condition` require a specific type is a waste of the generics.

```
public class Rule<T> {
  private Predicate<T> condition;
  //setter and getter
}

class ConditionFactory {
  public static Rule<Integer> intCondition() {
    Rule<Integer> rule = new Rule<>();
    rule.setCondition(l -> l == 0);
    return rule;
  }

  public static Rule<String> strCondition() {
    Rule<Integer> rule = new Rule<>();
    rule.setCondition(l -> l.length() > 3);
    return rule;
  }
}
```